# How to mask clip a multi ring pie in d3

Tags: d3.js, svg

[image]

I want to color these ring based on a percentage. So if a slice is 60%, it would be colored 60% of the way (first and second slice, last is uncolored). How would i go around doing that. Can i use clip/mask?

End result would be give me slices filled with color based on their percentage value. like a bar chart.

Comment: Why not simply using `opacity`?

Comment: opacity would work on the entire slice, i want to make the slice look half filled with color. based on percentage value

Comment: In that case just adjust the arc generator.

Comment: Use a radialGradient and set the stops appropriately.

Comment: I tried using Radial/Linear gradient. but having issues with cx,cy/x,y positions because they change throughout the slices

Comment: @JabranSaeed I don't exactly get what you want to achieve, can you put simple sketch(use paint, or pen ) or something to get an idea